# Can the karma-script-launcher also close something after the tests finish?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, karma-runner

I'm using the [karma-script-launcher](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-script-launcher) to open a virtual machine/browser/url but when the tests are complete I don't know how to close everything.

If I leave the browser open in the virtual machine it eventually stops trying to reconnect - no error message just fails to reconnect. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. I can't see why you wouldn't want the browser indefinitely trying to reconnect? What ever the reason it leaves me needing to close and re-open the browser each time I run the tests. But if I'm using the script launcher I don't see how this is possible.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure if this covers your answer but I stumbled over your question while looking for a solution to a similar issue, so let me explain - in case someone else encounters this issue.

Was running karma unit tests on codeship ci environment for a nodejs app.
Tests were successful, however the test would keep watching and wouldn't shut down, thus setting the tests to 'passed' - instead it would idle and after a while timeout, setting the tests to 'failed'.

Setting the option singleRun to true within the karma config helped.

Hope this helps anyone who's having the same issue.
Sorry if not topical enough :S

Comment: It's not quite what I'm getting at. The feature you're talking about is what I'm hoping to also achieve with the karma-script-launcher (mainly used for opening custom browsers). It can open them but doesn't have a way to close them after a single run. Thanks